# Reactjs creates infinite loop using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

Here is my App.js that contains beside Header and the MainView
an AlertDialog. Alert dialog has two state controlled props:

```
msg={alertMsg} toggleClass={alertToggleClass}
```

The task of AlertDialog is to show if the className is "alertDlg" and disappear if it's "alertDlg alertDlgClosed". Testing it via the inspector manually (changing className) shows, that it works fine.

Therefore alertToggleClass is set to "alertDlg alertDlgClosed" when initializing, so that the alert dialog is hided by default.

Within the MainView Component (before render())
`sendGlobalAlert("Test Alert Msg")` gets called which is simply a callback to the `showAlert(msg)` method in App.js.

Now here goes the tricky part: calling `setAlertToggleClass("alertDlg");` in `showAlert(msg)`-method shows the custom alert dialog as expected. However trying to disable it by calling `setAlertToggleClass("alertDlg alertDlgClosed");` within the setTimeout creates an infinite loop to `showAlert(msg)`-method.

As far as I can see, there is no recursivity is in `setTimeout(...)`.

I can't explain this behavior and would appreciate any helpful hints.

```
import './App.css';
import AlertDialog from './components/general/alert-dialog/AlertDialog';
import { Header } from './components/general/Header';
import MainView from './components/main/MainView';
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
    const [alertMsg,setAlertMsg] = useState(""); 
    const [alertToggleClass,setAlertToggleClass] = useState("alertDlg alertDlgClosed"); 

    function showAlert(msg){
        console.log("Showing alert dialog");
        setAlertMsg(msg); // set message
        setAlertToggleClass("alertDlg"); // show alert dialog
        
        setTimeout(function() {
            if(alertToggleClass === "alertDlg" ){
                setAlertToggleClass("alertDlg alertDlgClosed");
                console.log("hide alert");
            }
            // setAlertToggleClass("alertDlg test");
        },3500);
    }
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Header/>
            <MainView sendGlobalAlert={showAlert}/>
            <AlertDialog msg={alertMsg} toggleClass={alertToggleClass} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Would you mind if you could make a sandbox where you can show full code. If you like you can use https://codesandbox.io/ . This will make easier to understand what exactly is the problem.

Comment: It's preferred that the code be in the question itself as a [mcve] rather than an external sandbox. See [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support/338538#338538). That said -- `setAlertToggleClass("alertDlg")` is async and triggers a rerender, so you probably want to use a ref here rather than trying to read `alertToggleClass` in the `setTimeout`.

Comment: I think I figured out what the issue was... The called was immediately within the MainView, that is why it kept rerendering. Reducing the duration from 3500 to 100 helped to get react to it's limits, what resulted in an error : "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.". Will update the question with an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sendGlobalAlert("Test Alert Msg");` within the MainView was the issue here.

After this call, which is basically a callback to App.js's `showAlert(msg)` method, the props stored in state, that is used by AlertDialog, were changed. Due to an update to these props, AlertDialog rerendered and that again caused a rerender in App.js, which means that it elements had to rerender too. As it was including MainView, the rerender of App.js meant a rerender of MainView, which calls the `sendGlobalAlert("Test Alert Msg");` and started the recursiveness.

This is how the MainView looks like:

```
const MainView = ({sendGlobalAlert}) => {
    sendGlobalAlert("Test Alert Msg");
    return (
        <div className="main-view" >
            <BillView/>
            <InteractionView sendGlobalAlert={sendGlobalAlert}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```